# Swift: Integer Value not setting.

Tags: ios, swift

At the top of my ViewController class I have this variable:

```
var allInCategory: Int = 0
```

Then in the ViewDidLoad I have this call to a function and a print for the variable:

```
getRandomQuestion()
print(allInCategory)
```

in that function I have a Firebase call:

```
 let queryRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Questions").child(cat)
    queryRef2.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        
        self.allInCategory = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
      
        
    })
```

I seem to be having some issue getting a variable to change. In the console it is outputting:

> 0

if I put the print variable in the function like so:

```
let queryRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Questions").child(cat)
    queryRef2.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        
        self.allInCategory = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(self.allInCategory)
        
    })
```

The Output in the console is:

> 0
>
> 30

I thought maybe that this might be due to the time it takes to get that request from firebase. So I wrapped it in a dispatch group like so:

**ViewDidLoad**:

```
getRandomQuestion()

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("left group")
        print(self.allInCategory)
    })
```

and in the function:

```
group.enter()
    
    let queryRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Questions").child(cat)
    queryRef2.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        
     self.allInCategory = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
 
        
    })
    
group.leave()
```

but now the console output is like so:

> left group
>
> 0

Can anyone help me figure this out? I hope this is not something completely nooby i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `group.leave()` inside the completion block. This is the proper way to deal with asynchronous calls.

```
group.enter()

let queryRef2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Questions").child(cat)
queryRef2.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    self.allInCategory = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

    group.leave()
})
```